# Erlang open socket or know

Tags: sockets, erlang

How can i know socket open or not with erlang?

Comment: You may find the [Erlang `kernel inet` documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html) helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [erlang:port_info/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#port_info-1). It returns `undefined` if the socket is closed. For example:

```
Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> {ok,S} = gen_tcp:connect("localhost", 8000, [binary,{active,false}]).
{ok,#Port}
2> erlang:port_info(S).
[{name,"tcp_inet"},
 {links,[]},
 {id,634},
 {connected,},
 {input,0},
 {output,0}]
3> gen_tcp:close(S).
ok
4> erlang:port_info(S).
undefined
```

But be careful about using this for defensive programming, as that's not the Erlang way. It's better to make your code assume the socket is open, and if it hits an error because it tries to use an already-closed socket, let it crash and let something else like a supervisor handle the error.

Comment: This opens a client socket, not a server.

Comment: @rvirding True, but I must be missing your point -- you can replace the `gen_tcp:connect` call above with a call to `gen_tcp:listen` or `gen_tcp:accept` for example and call `erlang:port_info/1` on the sockets they return with the same results as the connect example shows.

Comment: Yes, of course, it will. My comment was just pointing out that this code was an example of how you open a client socket. For a server socket you need to use `gen_tcp:listen` and `gen_tcp:accept` as you said in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

try this in your terminal when your app reaches the point at which you want to know

```
inet:i()
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of sockets are you talking about? My guess is that most socket functions will return an error tuple if the socket is not open.